# Initial value of localparam enum using .first enumerated method

Tags: parameters, enums, system-verilog

Section 6.19.5.7 of IEEE 1800-2012 shows the following example for specifying the initial value of an enum variable:

```
typedef enum { red, green, blue, yellow } Colors;
Colors c = c.first;
```

Any reason the following should not also be allowed?  (I'm getting mixed result from certain tools.)

```
localparam Colors c_localparam = c_localparam.first;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Modelsim/Questa. And there's no reason other than someone forgot to write it down.

The LRM is not exhaustive in the list of methods that could be used as a constant function. There is an open issue for the next revision of the standard already filed.